# Play Framework: Storing co-ordinates in a db with ebeans in play framework

Tags: playframework-2.0, ebean

I am using play for the first time and am stuck in a maze. I am trying to store the value of top and left in the db along with the product name. I have managed to get pass the values to the controller but am not sure how to store it from there.

```
//controller
    @BodyParser.Of( play.mvc.BodyParser.Json.class )
        public static Result myMethod(){
            response().setContentType( "application/json" );
            JsonNode json = request().body().as(JsonNode.class);
            JsonNode jsonRequest = request().body().asJson();
            //left and top
            Double left= jsonRequest.findPath("Left").asDouble();
            Double top= jsonRequest.findPath("Top").asDouble();
            ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
            System.out.println("left " +left+"\ntop "+top);
            result.put("status", "OK");
            return ok(result);
        }
```

This is my db schema

```
@Entity 
public class Position extends Model {

    @Id 
    public long id;

    @Required
    public long left;

    @Required
    public long top;

    public static Finder<Long,Position> find = new Finder<Long,Position>(Long.class, Layout.class);
}
```

How do I save it using ebeans???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer to this one. All you have to do is convert it to Java Object from json.

```
//controller
@BodyParser.Of( play.mvc.BodyParser.Json.class )
    public static Result myMethod(){
        response().setContentType( "application/json" );
        ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
        JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
        Position p = Json.fromJson(json, Position.class);
        System.out.println(json);// to view in controller
        p.save();

        result.put("status", "OK");
        return ok(result);
    }
```